# Differential Equation -- Non-constant Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right) = 0$

I know that the solution is:

$\displaystyle u = C_1r + \frac{C_2}{r}$

but I am a little confused on how to arrive at that answer since the coefficients are not constant. I think it may be possible to convert this equation into a separable differential equation, but its not obvious to me how to do that.

Comment: Your solution seems incorrect. Is the OE $u''(r)+\frac{1}{r}u'(r)=0$?

Comment: I just tried plugging the solution back in and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chain rule:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)=0$$
$$u''+\frac{u'}{r}-\frac{u}{r^2}=0$$

This is Clearly Cauchy Euler Equation.
Can you solve it?

**Hint:**

> Use the assumption $$u=r^m \;\;\;\;\text{or even} \;\;\;\;u=r^{m+2}$$